# Python - TypeError when generating a list of dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, for-loop, typeerror

I am new to python, and I am looking for the pythonic way to indicate in my for loop that the range() in my for loop should return a string:

```
from pandas.tseries import offsets

years = []
for i in  range(1990,2020):
    offsets.YearBegin(years).append(i)
```

The above code throws off a TypeError that the int() argument can't be a list.  The hope is to return something like:

```
years = [1990-01-01,1991,01-01,...,2020-01-01]
```

Any help with a data type nood would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean `years.append(offsets.YearBegin(i))`?

Comment: I think I do!  This .chaining() thing in python is something I'm still getting my head around.  If you want to post that as an answer, i'd be happy to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have it:

```
years = []
for i in  range(1990,2020):
    years.append(offsets.YearBegin(i))
```

or even better:

```
years = [offsets.YearBegin(i) for i in range(1990,2020)]
```